# How can I use shortcodes in visual composer

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using visual composer and I have made a standard shortcode called '**fieldorigin**' in my theme functions file:

```
add_shortcode( 'fieldorigin', 'origin' );
function origin($atts) {
    //ob_start();
    return "hello";
    //return ob_get_clean();
}
```

And I was hoping to put this in the standard visual composer *'WP Text - Arbitrary text or HTML'* option where I wanted '**hello**' to appear: [fieldorigin] in a **form field value** - it is just a standard html form, name, email message etc.

However when i save my page and view it in the browser it still shows '[fieldorigin]' and not the word 'hello' as shown in my code above.

If I put the shortcode anywhere in the form (not as a field value) or before the form, it outputs 'hello' fine but I would like it as a form input field value.

as you can see from the above I have tried `ob_start();` and return `ob_get_clean();` but no luck.

Can anyone help, I have also tried the shortcode mapper built into visual composer but again no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Try with a regular text block and simply write your shortcode there.

[image: Write the shortcode here, or anywhere else]

Comment: Thanks that helped a bit, it seems the issue is I am trying to set it as a field input value, if I put the shortcode anywhere else, it shows 'hello' fine.

Comment: Please consider putting this as the accepted answer, if it solved the problem :)

`There is also the option of <?php do_shortcode("[fieldorigin]"); ?>`

In a PHP block, or if you have ezPHP plugin installed

Comment: to my understanding you can't put PHP into visual composer fields (in the admin) otherwise I would have used a simple PHP function and called that in the field - thus why I originally said shortcode, but that isn't working in a input field so until that works your answer helps but didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Hence why the aditional plugin

Comment: Look at this page https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Shortcode+Mapper , you can add your shortcode and it will become a element block you can drag and move around in your page. :-)